# Pytest cannot find a module in a different folder

Tags: python, pytest, pipenv

My Python project structure is

```
my_project
  src
    extensions
      my_tool.py
  tests
    main_test.py
  pytest.ini
  .env
```

In `main_test.py` I'm importing a class which is defined in `my_tool.py` like:

```py
from extensions import main_tool as tool

hammer = tool.Hammer()
```

I'm using Pipenv. I followed the these steps:

- Activated my env by running `pipenv shell`
- Installed pytest. `pipenv install -d pytest`

I even added `pytest.ini` file which has this content

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src/extensions
```

The file `.env` has

```
PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:src/extensions
```

I cannot get this to work. Whenever I run `pytest` from the root of my project I always get

```py
tests/main_test:1: in <module>
    from extensions import main_tool as tool
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extensions'
```

Comment: In `pytest.ini`: `pythonpath = src/`, because you importing `from extensions ...`

Comment: Thanks, It fixed my issue. To help others if you add this as an answer I will mark it as a correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to point `pythonpath` to `src` as you are using a `from extensions import ...`:

Change `pytest.ini` to:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = src/
```